# What are the differences between a Differential Change Map and a Bulk Change Map?

Tags: sql-server

What is the difference between a Differential Change Map and a Bulk Change Map?

Comment: please put the gist of the question in the title. "SQL Server" is not a question. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

The following MSDN article defines these SQL Server page types:

[SQL Server 2008 Books Online: Understanding Pages and Extents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969.aspx)

> **Bulk Changed Map**
>
> Information about extents modified by bulk operations since the last BACKUP LOG statement per allocation unit.
>
> **Differential Changed Map**
>
> Information about extents that have changed since the last BACKUP DATABASE statement per allocation unit.